# Converting characters to numeric in dataframe

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe, "Election2000" with a column factor "presvote". Presvote has 3 possible values: "republican", "democrat", "NA".

How do I create a new variable, RVote, that converts all republican values to the value 1, and democrat values to 0?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use R w/o a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are looking for is:

```
Election2000$RVote <- as.numeric(Election2000$presvote=="republican")
```

Edit: It works with this example data frame:

```
presvote <- c("democrat", "republican", "democrat", NA, "republican")
Election2000 <- data.frame(presvote)
Election2000$presvote <- as.factor(Election2000$presvote)
```

Comment: Election2000$presvote automatically assigns numeric values 1, and 2 to republican and democrat. How do I switch these to 1 and 0 instead?

Comment: @user4579 I need to see what you're looking at to know how to answer that. When you type Election2000$presvote , what does R return? Is it a factor column, or a numeric one?

Comment: A factor column. I need to switch the factors from 1,2 to 0,1 to run logit and probit regressions

Comment: @user4579 then I think the line above should work:
 Election2000\$RVote <- as.numeric(Election2000\$presvote=="republican") .
But if it does not, try:
 Election2000\$RVote <- as.numeric(as.numeric(Election2000\$presvote)==2) .
You should then have a new column, RVote, containing 0, 1 and NA values.

Comment: @user4579 or more concisely: `Election2000$RVote <- as.numeric(Election2000$presvote)-1`

Comment: `Election2000$RVote <- as.numeric(Election2000$presvote)-2` worked. Thanks.